# Please help to identify my JS/JQuery mistakes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my attempt at [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pse5H/3/) (never used it before).

I use:

- JQuery
- Bootstrap 3
- JQuery UI

Here's the entire code in a single **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="productTitle">Product</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productTitle" placeholder="Product title"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="categorySelect"></label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="categorySelect">
                        <option value="" selected>Category</option>
                        <option value="one">One</option>
                        <option value="two">Two</option>
                        <option value="three">Three</option>
                        <option value="four">Four</option>
                        <option value="five">Five</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <label for="price">Current Price</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6" id="price">
                        <div class="input-group" id="priceFrom">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priceFromValue"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group" id="priceTo">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priceToValue"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12" id="priceRangeSlider">
                    <!-- Range Slider from JQuery UI -->
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="closeDate" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="closeDateIcon"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>        


                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
                    <label for="numberOfBids">Number of Bids</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberOfBids"/>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block" id="find">Find now</button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScripts -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS for HTML elements -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#priceRangeSlider').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 5000,
                values: [ 1000, 1500 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $('#priceFromValue').val(value, ui.values[0]);
                    $('#priceToValue').val(value, ui.values[1]);    
                }
            });

            $( "#priceFromValue" ).val( $( "#priceRangeSlider" ).slider( "values", 0) );
            $( "#priceToValue" ).val( $( "#priceRangeSlider" ).slider( "values", 1) );

            $( "closeDate" ).datepicker();    

            $("#closeDateIcon").click(function(event){
                datepicker( "show" );
            });

        });
    </script>    

</body>

</html>
```

I have two groups of elements that require additional JQuery wiring:

1. `PriceRange Slider` (from [`JQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range))
2. `DatePicker` (from [`JQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)) that I tried to combine with `Bootstrap 3` add-on

None of this functionality actually works. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pse5H/8/

I changed these two lines from:

```
$('#priceFromValue').val(value, ui.values[0]);
$('#priceToValue').val(value, ui.values[1]);
```

to

```
$('#priceFromValue').val(ui.values[0]);
$('#priceToValue').val(ui.values[1]);
```

The variable "values" is undefined.

Missed the piece re: date picker, your selector is off, should be:

```
$( "#closeDate" ).datepicker();
```

as the # represents selection via ID

To get the datepicker to show on icon click, need to specify which datepicker you wish to show.

```
datepicker( "show" );// was
$('#closeDate').datepicker("show");//now
```

Comment: Two more questions: (**1**) What about adjusting the slider based on user changes in `From` and `To` input fields?  (**2**) Is there a way to trigger `datepicker` when users click on `calendar glyphicon` as well?

Comment: I updated the fiddle to reflect the from/to changes via text input to change the slider values. And to have the datepicker show when you click the icon.

Comment: No problem, if you're doing a lot of dynamic client side code, I'd suggest you take a look at some of the libraries that support data binding to make your code more manageable and maintainable. angular, ember, knockout to name a few.

Comment: Yes, I will be using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

For the slider, in the `slide` callback, you're referencing a local `value` variable that doesn't exist. If you change it to

```
    $('#priceFromValue').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#priceToValue').val(ui.values[1]);
```

I think you'll get your desired behavior.

As for the datepicker, you're missing a `#` in your selector. You'll want to change it to

```
$( "#closeDate" ).datepicker();
```